# Merging an unregistered account

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, merge-accounts, unregistered-users

I realized, after many months, that I once asked a question on the [aviation Stack Exchange site](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour), not from this account. Apparently I reentered my email I guessed and created an account which was separate, but I had the same name and mail account.

How can I merge the accounts? I am not sure I can log in to the "unregistered" account.

Here's a photo:

[image]